# Сохранение значения Angle (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

В wpf создал фигуру Tank. С помощью анимации изменяю значение углов , с помощью клавиши А, влево на 90 градусов. но нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы значения углов сохранялись, поскольку сейчас, если нажать А ещё раз, то анимация повторяется с начальной точки. Не понимаю как сделать это. Если есть более простой способ изменения угла, был бы рад узнать о нем

```
if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Tank, Canvas.GetLeft(Tank) - 5);

            //var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
            Tank.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
            Tank.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

            rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(
                RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
                new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    By = -90,
                    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5),
                    //RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Создайте переменную в не блока в которую будете записывать текущие значение и его менять

Comment: это тоже мне пришло в голову. Но как передать текущее значение angle? какое свойство за это отвечает? можете, пожалуйста, прислать работающий пример?

Comment: У Tank должно быть это свойство

Answer (score 0):

Решил, но не знаю насколько это правильно. Создал новый экземпляр класса RotateTransform. Вынес за "нажатие на кнопку" свойство и при нажатии передаю значение этому свойству. Проблема решена.

```
var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();

        Tank.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
        //Tank.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);


        if (e.Key == Key.D)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Tank, Canvas.GetLeft(Actor) + 5);
            rotateTransform.Angle = +90;
        }
```